# How to clone a RectangleF

Tags: c#, copy, geometry, clone, system.drawing

How do you easily clone (copy) a `RectangleF` in C#?

There are obviously inelegant ways to do it, such as `new RectangleF(r.Location, r.size)`, but surely there's a `.Copy` or `.Clone` method hiding somewhere?  But neither of those compiles for me, nor does there appear to be a copy constructor.  I suspect there's some simple, C#-standard way of copying any struct, that I just haven't found yet.

In case it matters, my real objective is to make a method that returns an offset version of a rectangle (because, amazingly, `RectangleF` doesn't have such built in - it has only a mutator method).  My best stab at this is:

```
public static RectangleF Offset(RectangleF r, PointF offset) {
    PointF oldLoc = r.Location;
    return new RectangleF(new PointF(oldLoc.X+offset.X, oldLoc.Y+offset.Y), r.Size);
}
```

(Made uglier than it should by be the astounding lack of an addition operator for `PointF`, but that's another issue.)  Is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RectangleF is a struct i.e. a value type. Consider the following:

```
public class Program
{
    struct S
    {
        public int i;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        S s1 = new S();
        S s2 = s1;

        s1.i = 5;

        Console.WriteLine(s1.i);
        Console.WriteLine(s2.i);
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
5
0
```

Because S is a struct i.e. s2 is a copy of s1.

Comment: Thank you (and thanks @jdv-Jan de Vaan, too).  I knew I must be missing something obvious!  The use of the "new" operator had me thinking I was working with references, but now I see that that's not true in C#.

Answer (score 3):

A `Rect` is a struct, a value type.

To clone it just assign it to a new variable.